# Exclude Column in Azure MobileService TableController

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am writing a WindowsPhone app with Azure MobileServices and wanted to expose the database to the client using TableControllers.

```
public IQueryable<Activity> GetAllActivities()
{
    return Query();
}
```

But how can I filter the data my controller returns to the client? 
I already found out, that I can filter rows using Where(..).

But is there a way to exclude columns from the resultset?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it, but depends on requirements:

**1 - Using specific dtos mapped with a model**

You can create Dtos that are mapped with the model from Azure Mobile Service and the model is connected with the database. Dtos do not need to expose all my model, something like

I can have

```
public class MyDto
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and my model can be

```
public class MyModel
{
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public string Details {get;set;}
}
```

then is need to mapped them, in Azure Mobile Service normally we uses AutoMapper

**2 - Using the method "Select" from Linq**

In the client application you can do something like

```
_client.GetTable<YourObject>().Select(x => new YourObject()
{
    Prop1 = x.Prop1,
    Prop2 = x.Prop2,
}
```

When you need to do queries you should use Linq.

Comment: Thanks, dtos with automapper does the job! :)

Answer (score 0):

one good option for you would be overwriting your EntityDomainManager.

What I mean is creating a new class call it for example KhosroItemDomainManager

```
public class KhosroItemDomainManager : MappedEntityDomainManager<YourModelHere, YourEntityHere>
{
    public KhosroItemDomainManager(DbContext context, 
        System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, ApiServices services): base(context, request, services)
    { }

    public override IQueryable<YourModelHere> Query()
    {
        MobileServiceContext ctx = this.Context as MobileServiceContext;

        var items = from ai in ctx.YourModelHere
            select new AuctionItem
            {
                Name = ai.Name,
                Description = ai.Description,

            };

        return items;
    }

    public override System.Web.Http.SingleResult<YourModelHere> Lookup(string id)
    {
        var ctx = Context as MobileServiceContext;
        var item = from ai in ctx.AuctionItems
                   where ai.Id == id
                   select new AuctionItem
                   {
                       Id = ai.Id,
                       Description = ai.Description,

                   };

        return new System.Web.Http.SingleResult<YourModelHere>(item);
    }

    public override Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string id)
    {
        return base.DeleteItemAsync(id);
    }
    public override Task<YourModelHere> UpdateAsync(string id, System.Web.Http.OData.Delta<YourModelHere> patch)
    {
        return base.UpdateEntityAsync(patch, id);
    }


}
```

as simple as that, basically, all you need to do is creating your own domain manager.  and override the Query, Lookup , DeleteAsync and UpdateAsync

after that you need to go back to your Controller and replace this part with

```
 protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<YourModelHere>(context, Request,       Services);
    }
```

with

```
 protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new KhosroItemDomainManager(context, Request, Services);
    }
```